# facebook likes are not showing on facebook wall without comment in php

Tags: facebook

The issue is someone click the like button, the facebook popup is being coming and user click on "post to facebook" button. The liked page is not showing on the facebook wall.. if we write comment in comment box and then click post to facebook button then it appears on the wall.

For eg. click on the like button on this page http://www.bitcandy.com/plogs/plogDedicated/music/best-song-ever-lana-del-rey-video-games and do not write any comment and click on post to facebook. It will not show on your wall.. If you write a comment then it will be there …

may be you found the issue which I want to explain.. let me know if you know about this..

Thanks